# Android developer options "show Touches"

Tags: android, performance, touch

I am wondering to know how Android implements this half-transparent white ball.

This is a good tool to know the input lag in the touch event.

However, to get the value precisely, I need to know how Android does this.

Please let me know if you have any clue.

Thanks

Comment: well, interesting enough to have a -1 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after tracing the source code,

I found that the white ball appearing after checking the show touches option in developer options is implemented in PointerController.cpp.

You can try to trace this source to know things more detail if you are interested in this topic.

Comment: I added touch.gestureMode = spots , to my touchscreen device IDC file, but I don't see any touched spots on screen yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the following to get the touch value:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            switch(action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                int x = (int)event.getX();
                int y = (int)event.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int x1 = (int)event.getX();
                int y1 = (int)event.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int)event.getY();

                default:

                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```